# Oracle apex classic report hidden column

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a classic report region in my oracle apex application, with query

```
SELECT SENDER,SUBJECT,SDATE,MAIL_NO
FROM MAIL
```

I want to hide the column 'MAIL_NO' but also want to access its value in front end, so I can not use *hidden column* property of classic report. I need one more similiar region in the same page so that I can not use tabular form and it's *hidden column save state* property of tabular column. How can I achieve this using classic report in oracle apex ?

Comment: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2019/05/hiding-html-when-downloading-an-interactive-report/ check this post hope it helps

Comment: No. By this way, I have to show the value. I dont want to show it in my form. I just want to hide it and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

try putting this in inline css in the main page

```
#MAIL_NO, /*header*/
td[headers="MAIL_NO"]/*rows*/
{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reach the column value using Substitution Strings. for example if you want to use the column value as a link to detail page. [for more details about Substitution Strings visit the oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03022)

Answer (score 0):

Hide the column and put it in another item (also hidden item) and you could use it
more info 
https://jackiemcilroy.blogspot.com/2018/03/delete-row-of-report-with-dynamic-action.html